# Highest frequency in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am looking for a way to get the highest frequency in the entire pandas, not in a particular column. I have looked at value count, but it seems that works in a column specific way. Any way to do that?

Comment: you can use pandas df.max - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html#pandas-dataframe-max

Comment: `df.stack().mode()` ..?

Comment: df.stack().mode() worked perfectly. It is printing the most frequent entries, but any way to print their frequency as well? Thanks

Comment: `df.stack().value_counts().head(1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`Series.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html) for top values, for first select by position:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'B':[4,5,4,5,4,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],

})

a = df.stack().mode().iat[0]
print (a)
4
```

Or if need also frequency is possible use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
s = df.stack().value_counts()
print (s)
4    6
5    4
3    3
9    2
7    2
2    2
1    2
8    1
6    1
0    1
dtype: int64

print (s.index[0])
4

print (s.iat[0])
6
```